# Multiple children in scrollview

Tags: android

Is there a way to have more than one child in scrollview using a constraint layout? I'm new to coding so any help would be appreciated. I am using the latest version of android studio.

Comment: ScrollViews can only have **exactly 1** child. But it can be a layout or a ViewGroup, Therefore, a container of other Views. But there are situations where you don't even need a ScrollView, since some ViewGroups (i.e.: ListViews or RecyclerViews) are scrollable by themselves.

Comment: unfortunately scrollview can only have one direct child, but you can add a child layout in scrollview inside which you can add all the child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to add more than one child into **ScrollView** / **HorizontalScrollView** / **NestedScrollView**

Google doc says next:

> A view group that allows the view hierarchy placed within it to be scrolled. Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it. To add multiple views within the scroll view, make the direct child you add a view group, for example LinearLayout, and place additional views within that LinearLayout.

[android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the children into a FrameLayout or so.

```
-> ScrollView     
   \-> FrameLayout
       \-> Child 1
       \-> Child 2
       \-> Child 3
```

If you want them to be one below each other use a `LinearLayout` and set `android:orientation="vertical"`.